# Name of the snack (possibly Indian)

Tags: snacks

I wanted to ask if anyone have any idea what is the name of that snack that can be seen on top of a salad, between burgers.

[image: Burgers with snack]

I know the name in my country, but now, in Canada I can't find it anywhere.

Appreciate any help!

Tom

Comment: We'll see what people have to say, but often, these kinds of things don't have English names, so it's hard to offer much besides suggesting finding the right kind of grocery store.

Comment: So how are the d... things called in your fine country? That would give a good starting point to people...

Answer (score 3):

This is funny because:
In English they are called " fried snacks" :)
But it's a polish thing, they are called "przysmak świętokrzyski" or "crates". It's basically wheat flour (97,5%) and water. Then fried. 
I think there is only one company that make them https://www.wspspolem.com.pl/produkty/snack-przysmak-swietokrzyski/snack-kratka/ and although they write there are other shapes I have never ever seen anything beside crates.

BUT
I have eaten something similar in England but they were sweet, it's called Jalebi.

Comment: Yes, that good old English word jalebi!  Seriously, it's just a piece of garnish, of Hindi origin.  Not so different to some establishments putting crisps on a plate.

Comment: @dougal you know that English like to wait for other languages in dark alleys and then rob them of loose words.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they have a name in English. A known brand name of a snack made from the same material is Pom Bears, but just like the grid thingies, it is very strongly associated with the shape, to the point where a snack with the same content but different shape will be considered to be a different "thing".

You can try calling them "crisps" but even in the UK, asking for crisps is likely to get you the non-puffy version, not any shape of the puffy one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Vada Pav".

[Vada Pav](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Vada_Pav.jpg/400px-Vada_Pav.jpg)

It's a typical Indian street dish consisting of spiced potato, deep-fried and served in a bun. Various sauces and toppings are common.

[Link to Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vada_pav)

Comment: I think you misread the question - it is about "that snack that can be seen on top of a salad, between burgers". So whatever is served in the bun is not part of the question, it is the small fried grid between them.

Comment: @rumtscho yes, I sure did.