# What is this food?

Tags: deep-frying, chips

I buy these in Morocco. In the state seen in the picture, they are hard and inedible. When you put them into hot oil, they inflate, doubling in size, and become soft and edible. We call them "chips", but I don't think they are. What are they ?[image]

Comment: Could it be one of these: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81249/? They are hard before being fried, and related to potato chips of the pressed flakes variety. And the factory can change their shape and color, they don't have to be grids. So I guess I'm asking, do they look that way when fried? Crispy rather than soft, and with many air holes inside?

Comment: @rumtscho: that classifies as an answer.  If you post an answer and ping me, I'll come back and upvote...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a snack which puffs up during frying, and [has no standard name in English](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81249/name-of-the-snack-possibly-indian). A popular brand in Europe is Pom Bears, which is shaped like 2D bears.

They start out looking like raw store-bought noodles. When deep fried, they puff up and expand, a bit like puffed rice, and get crispy and airy. If you tried classifying them, you could end up declaring them a subtype of chips (UK: crisps) but they are certainly not the thing people imagine when they hear the term.

Comment: You might consider it to be a varient of a papadum

Comment: I wouldn't really consider it a variant of papadum, for me the two foods are very dissimilar.